# How to split a string after a dot UNLESS the characters after the dot are numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I need to take only the letters and numbers at the beginning of a string, but some numbers are decimals. The strings are not all formatted the same. Here are a few examples of some of the data and what I would need returned:

HB61 .M16 1973       I need HB61 returned

HB97.52 .R6163 1982  I need HB97.52 returned

HB98.V38 1994        I need HB98 returned

HB 119.G74 A3 2007   I need HB119 returned

I'm very new to coding so I'm hoping there's some simple solution that I just don't know?

I was going to just split it at the first dot and then get rid of the spaces, but this wouldn't allow me to keep the decimals such as HB97.52 which I need. I currently have code written just to test one string at a time. The code is as follows:

```
data = input("Data: ")    
components = data.split(".")    
str(components)    
print(components[0].replace(" ", ""))
```

This works as expected except for the strings with decimals. for HB97.52 .R6163 1982 I would like HB97.52 returned but it only returns HB97.

Comment: All numbers that you use are decimal, but some are floating-point. Also, "HB 119" contains a space, do you want spaces, too?

Comment: No, I do not want the spaces. I was just showing various formats of the data. I'm going to need to take the data which is returned and run it against a registry like a range Vlookup would do in Excel.

Comment: But there is a space in "HB 119"

Comment: Yes, the data set I'm working with has some formatted incorrectly with a space in between the first two letters and the numbers afterwards. I only need the HB119 returned from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regular expression extracts the letters at the beginning of a string, followed by optional spaces, followed by a [possibly floating point] number:

```
s = ['HB61 .M16 1973', 'HB97.52 .R6163 1982', 
     'HB98.V38 1994', 'HB 119.G74 A3 2007']

import re
pattern = r"^[a-z]+\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
[re.findall(pattern, part, flags=re.I)[0] for part in s]
#['HB61', 'HB97.52', 'HB98', 'HB 119']
```

If you do not want the spaces in the output, this slightly different pattern extracts the letter part and the number part separately, and then they are joined:

```
pattern = r"(^[a-z]+)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
list(map("".join, [re.findall(pattern, part, flags=re.I)[0] for part in s]))
#['HB61', 'HB97.52', 'HB98', 'HB119']
```

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how do you display the output of this?

Comment: Just `print` it

Comment: Yeah. I figured it out after I commented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For something like HB61.45.78.R5000 what do you want? If you want HB61.45.78 then use this first snippet:

```
data = data.replace(' ', '')
data = data.split('.')
wanted = data[0]
for i in range(1,len(data)):
   if data[i][0].isalpha():
      break
   else:
      wanted += '.' + data[i]
```

Otherwise, if you want only HB61.45 then use

```
data = data.replace(' ', '')
data = data.split('.')
wanted = data[0]
if not data[1][0].isalpha():
   wanted += '.' + data[1]
```